# POST data sent from VueJs to server is in strange format

Tags: rest, vue.js, vuejs2, codeigniter-3

I've been working on simple function for sending mail, but when I post data to my server it's in strange format.

This is my VueJs script

```
sendEmail: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let object = {name: this.name, email: this.email, subject: this.subject, message: this.message};
    this.$http.post(this.$apiUrl + `rest/api/public/Contact/Contact`, object, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
    })
}
```

And this is my rest api (written in CodeIgniter REST Library)

```
class Contact extends REST_Controller {

    public function contact_post() {
        var_dump($_POST);
        die();
        .....
    }
.....
```

And this is the output of var_dump($_POST)

```
array(2) {
  ["{"name":"testt","email":"test@gmail_com","subject":"testt","message":"testt_testt"}"]=>
  string(0) ""
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

The question is, what em I doing wrong? Probably this is not normal format of data, so how to format it properly, so I will be able to fetch data on my server side. If you need any additional informations, please let me know and i will provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer on [Github](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/350#issuecomment-227270046)

Yes, StringClient uses the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format by default while axios uses application/json by default (when data is an Object).

So current implementation looks like this

```
var params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('name', this.name);
params.append('email', this.email);
params.append('subject', this.subject);
params.append('message', this.message);
this.$http.post(this.$apiUrl + `rest/api/public/Contact/Contact`, params, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
})
```